# How are string io::Errors created

Tags: error-handling, rust, std, traits

Rust [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Error.html#examples) show a `std::io::Error` being created using

```
let custom_error = Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, "oh no!");
```

and `new` has a [type signature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Error.html#method.new) of

```
fn new<E>(kind: ErrorKind, error: E) -> Error 
  where E: Into<Box<std::error::Error + Send + Sync>>
```

I've found an [implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html) of `impl<T: std::error::Error> std::error::Error for Box<T>` but cannot find one for `&'static str` like the one used in the example.

What trait is used to achieve `Into<Error>` for strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given:

- `impl<'a> From<&'a str> for Box<Error>` (see the [`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) docs)
- `impl<T, U> Into<U> for T where U: From<T>` (see the [`Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html) docs)

Substitute `T = &'a str` and `U = Box<Error>`, which gives you:

- `impl<'a> Into<Box<Error>> for &'a str`